# How to identify a process which has no pid?

Tags: networking, security, process

I have a process which listen to 2 ports : 45136/tcp and 37208/udp (actually I assume it is the same process). But netstat doesn't return any pid :

```
netstat -antlp | grep 45136
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45136           0.0.0.0:*           LISTEN      -
```

Same result with "grep 37208".

I tried lsof too :

```
lsof -i TCP:45136
```

But it doesn't return anything. 
It's a new installation of squeeze and I really don't know what could be this process. Any idea ?

**ANSWER**
Thanks to your comments I found out what it was. I deinstalled nfs-server nfs-common (after a dkpg --get-selections | grep nfs search) and the unknown process disapeared.
Strange though that kernel processes aren't marked in any way.

Thanks again to both of you. ;)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

#### netstat

There's a process there, your userid just isn't privy to seeing what it is. This is a layer of protection provided by `lsof` that's keeping you from seeing this. Simply re-run the command but prefix it using the `sudo` command instead.

```
$ sudo netstat -antlp | grep 45136
```

There's even a warning about this in the output of `lsof` at the top.

> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

#### Example

```
$ netstat -antlp | grep 0:111
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      -                   

$ sudo netstat -antlp | grep 0:111
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      1248/rpcbind
```

#### ss

If you're not having any luck with `netstat` perhaps `ss` will do. You'll still need to use `sudo`, and the output can be a little bit more cryptic.

#### Example

```
$ ss -apn|grep :111
LISTEN     0      128         :::111             :::*     
LISTEN     0      128          *:111              *:*     

$ sudo ss -apn|grep :111
LISTEN     0      128         :::111             :::*      users:(("rpcbind",1248,11))
LISTEN     0      128          *:111              *:*      users:(("rpcbind",1248,8))
```

#### Process ID still not there?

There are instances where there simply isn't a PID associated to the TCP port in use. You can read about NFS, in [@derobert's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97764/7453), which is one of them. There are others. I have instances where I'm using ssh tunnels to connect back to services such as IMAP. These are showing up without a process ID too.

In any case you can use a more verbose form of `netstat` which might shed additional light on what process is ultimately using a TCP port.

```
$ netstat --program --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports --extend
```

#### Example

```
$ netstat --program --numeric-hosts --numeric-ports --extend |grep -- '-' | head -10
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       User       Inode      PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.103:936           192.168.1.3:60526           ESTABLISHED root       160024310  -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:2049            192.168.1.3:841             ESTABLISHED sam        159941218  -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:143               127.0.0.1:57443             ESTABLISHED dovecot    152567794  13093/imap-login    
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.103:739           192.168.1.3:2049            ESTABLISHED root       160023970  -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.103:34013         192.168.1.3:111             TIME_WAIT   root       0          -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46110             127.0.0.1:783               TIME_WAIT   root       0          -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.102:54891         107.14.166.17:110           TIME_WAIT   root       0          -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                127.0.0.1:36565             TIME_WAIT   root       0          -                   
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.1:2049            192.168.1.6:798             ESTABLISHED tammy      152555007  -
```

If you notice the output includes INODES so we could back track into the process using this info.

```
$ find -inum 152555007
```

Which will show you a file which might lead you to a process.

#### References

- [Port to PID](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Port_to_PID)

Comment: @derobert - I was thinking they were threads.

Comment: @slm (userspace) threads have PIDs.

Comment: @derobert - that's what I thought but was double checking to be sure.

Comment: @derobert - I found this: "The Linux kernel itself provides the NFS server (aka "knfsd"). Thus there is no associated process because the kernel is not a process."

Comment: @JohnDoe - it might be that they're related to NFS.

Comment: @slm Thanks for the edit : I added this to my aliases. ;)

Comment: Thanks!!! I always wondered why some showed PID and some dont. Running netstat with sudo lists all as expected!

Comment: If you try this inside a docker container: run `docker exec` with `--privileged` to obtain *real* root priviledges.

Answer (score 22):

Another option is that the socket doesn't belong to a process, it belongs to the kernel. One common example of this is NFS.

```
Watt:~# netstat -ltp | egrep -- '-[[:space:]]*$'
tcp        0      0 *:nfs                   *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 *:48131                 *:*                     LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:55607              [::]:*                  LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 [::]:nfs                [::]:*                  LISTEN      -
```

I'm not sure a good way, in general, to identify these. In the particular case of NFS, `rpcinfo` will often be able to tell us:

```
anthony@Watt:~$ rpcinfo -p | grep 48131
    100021    1   tcp  48131  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  48131  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  48131  nlockmgr
```

Unfortunately, that only works for IPv4. To get v6, you have to leave off `-p`, which then displays port numbers in a silly manner: As two additional octets of IP address. Port 55607 thus becomes *217.55* (because *217* × 256 + *55* = 55607):

```
anthony@Watt:~$ rpcinfo  | grep -i 217.55
    100021    1    tcp6      ::.217.55              nlockmgr   superuser
    100021    3    tcp6      ::.217.55              nlockmgr   superuser
    100021    4    tcp6      ::.217.55              nlockmgr   superuser
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `rpcinfo -p` only works for IPv4